# PHP merge Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, I need to merge them into a single but using array_merge values ​​fray and the final array incorrect. I try $array1+$array2, but the same thing happens.

And at the moment I have no idea how to fix it.

UPDATE: in my case array_merge and array_merge_recursive return the same result (data from the last of the array overwrites the rest)

UPDATE2: my fail for those arrays work well, I applied to other. Thanks problem solved (after Stijn I realized that it is better to merge arrays first and then apply my transformation)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DOC_DATE] => 20.09.13
            [LINK] => <a href="http://lk.ruli24.local.ru/xreports/viewreport_prx.php?d_name=&format=pdf&id=&remake=1&doc=35428 "> ������� </a>
            [QUERY_ID] => 
            [DOC] => 35428
            [DOC_TYPE] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DOC_DATE] => 20.09.13
            [LINK] => <a href="http://lk.ruli24.local.ru/xreports/viewreport_prx.php?d_name=&format=pdf&id=&remake=1&doc=35428 "> ������� </a>
            [QUERY_ID] => 
            [DOC] => 35428
            [DOC_TYPE] => 
        )
```

Comment: Can you post your actual arrays instead of the array dumps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead.

> **array_merge_recursive()** merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the
>   previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for
>   these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done
>   recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the
>   function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array
>   too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later
>   value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2)`